# selection by attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-location

I have a problem with selection by location:

I need Arcgis to automatically count for each of my bus itinerary (see capture) how many times a" polygone " will be " within a distance of the source layer 100 meters" .

Is there any king of script or models that!can help me to automatize this selection

If not any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "feature", but in order to get the number of itinerary within a distance of each polygon, you can use the spatial join tool, with "join_one_to_one" and "within_a_distance" options. If your itineraries are not in the same feature class, you first need to merge them (and maybe dissolve based on the itinerary identifier)